# Condition for the unseparability of Banach Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

A basic question but I can't quite resolve it:

Why is the following equivalent to unseparability of a Banach space X:

For some uncountable set S $\subseteq$ X, there exists $\delta$ > 0 such that for any $x_1$, $x_2$ $\in$ S, norm of $x_1$ - $x_2$ $\ge$ $\delta$

I realise this means there any no cauchy sequences in S, hence no convergent sequences other than those which are eventually just constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Consider family of open balls $$\left\{\mathrm{Ball}\left(x,\frac{\delta}{2}\right):x\in S\right\}$$

Comment: I see that that is an uncountable family of disjoint open sets, whose union is S, but I don't see how to proceed

Comment: I see that if S were a space, we could say: If X is a separable space, then S is separable (since subspaces of Separable Metric spaces are separable). Then I can see that this is impossible: an uncountable space with no convergent sequences other than those which are eventually just constant is clearly not separable. However S is a set here, not a space!

Comment: their union is not $S$ but anyway... now for each ball pick a point from dence suset of $X$ (assume it does exist). Now get a contradiction

Comment: Yes sorry, with S $\subseteq$ their union  . Suppose X is separable, then let D be countable, such that its closure is X. D contains points arbitrarily close to each point in X, hence contains a point in each set in the family above. So D contains uncountably many distinct points, contradiction. Brilliant, thanks! Gradually getting to grips with this notion

Comment: keep going and don't hesitate to ask MSE community